# Elementor loop grid

Tags: wordpress, elementor, web-deployment-project

I am building a website using wordpress, elementor pro and woocommerce. I wanted to use the loop grid because I wanted a customised product items. So heres my problem, the pagination is not working when I am selecting "current query" inside a product archive template. It is working in the elementor builder but when I save it and view the cagegory page there is no pagination and It is displaying all the products inside that category (not getting the posts per page i set in the loop grid element).

Thank you!

I tried setting the posts per page in the settings "reading"

Comment: You can try filter hooks to modify the category page query